# How can I relink an element to a clouded CC Library element?

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, adobe-library

In my **InDesign** document, one of the elements needs to be relinked.

I would like to relink it to a clouded, CC library element present in the CC Libraries panel, and thus not lost position, properties, scale, etc.

[But when I select "Relink from CC Library", then click on an element in the CC Library panel, nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHWPg.jpg)

**How does one relink an element from the CC Libraries panel?**

<sub>*Version:
InDesign 2021 v16.1 on macOS Catalina*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After choosing *Relink from CC Library* the *CC Libraries* panel pops up. Then you click the asset you want and click the *Relink* button in the bottom of the panel.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Wolff! AI really has a UX issue when the "Relink" button I'm looking for is literally the least visible thing on the screen!

Comment: I agree. It's a strange interface. Never use CC Libraries myself. Took some time to crack the riddle. 

Comment: Honestly I wasn't using them for the longest time but if you produce graphics for a brand who needs a style you can just put a character or brand assets and icon library in there and then it's all drag and drop illustration, like posing elements

Comment: What threw me off was that it says "Cancel Relink".